# Flutter Error FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: flutter, dart

```
  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'F:\Flutter New Application (Game Conduct)\gamershub\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> ASCII
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get 
more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 21s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        23.6s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

My build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
  }
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
 }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I am getting the error while running the flutter apk event i have no issues in command flutter doctor -v. But when i try to run my code i am gettent the error. Even after i have created the new project using flutter create i am getting the the same error in that project also.

Comment: Try `flutter clean`.. hopefully, that solves your issue..

Comment: i have tried this also but i am getting the  same error

Comment: Error says that the issue exist in `\android\app\build.gradle` and you've contents of file `\android\build.gradle`.